# Spark's .tgz File cannot be extracted on Google Colab?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-colaboratory

Running these seem to work:

```
# Download Java Virtual Machine (JVM)
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
!wget -q https://dlcdn.apache.org/spark/spark-3.3.0/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz
```

Then the following line does not work and produces this error:

`!tar xf spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz`

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

When I do `!pwd`, I am in the same folder as where my `spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz` is located.

Here is a screen shot:
[image]

Comment: this works perfectly when I try on colab.

Comment: @samkart I've attached a screen shot of my error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Extracted from OP's question:*

> For everyone else having this same error, forget the whole thing.
> There is a much easier way with 5 lines of code.
>
> Run these instead and Pyspark should automatically be set up in Google
> Colab:
>
> ```
> !pip install pyspark
>
> # Import SparkSession 
> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
> # Create a Spark Session 
> spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
> # Check Spark Session Information 
> spark
>
> # Import a Spark function 
> from library from pyspark.sql.functions import col
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove the `-q` flag from the `wget` command and see what's happening.

The thing is, I could only reproduce your problem with the following actions:

1. Suppose I accidentally tried to download Spark from the following link (redirector link):

```
!wget -q https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-3.3.0/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz
```

The command above downloaded the file, but it's basically html, only with the filename `spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz`.

2. Suppose also that later I discovered my mistake, and decided to download from the proper link. I removed the `-q` flag to show what's happening:

```
!wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/spark/spark-3.3.0/spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz
2022-09-12 12:03:09 (224 MB/s) - ‘spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz.1’ saved [299321244/299321244]
```

Since I already have the file spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz, `wget` downloads with another filename.

3. So, when I try to unpack the file, basically I'm trying to unpack the first downloaded file, i.e. the wrong one:

```
!tar xf spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: The error unfortunately is persisting - I've updated my screen shot above without the `-q` flag.

Comment: I renamed it to `spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz.5` and it seems to work. Thank you!